# C++ dynamically linked library and void pointer

Tags: c++, c, dll, dlopen

I'm in the following situation: I'm writing a C++ program which has to dynamically load a C++ library (i.e. via `dlopen` and friends in Linux and `LoadLibrary` and friends in Windows). This can be done creating a C interface.

Now, both in the program and in the library I manage some object which has some specified template members and some methods:

```
struct MyObject {
    std::vector<int> _vec;
    //...
    void do_something();
};
```

Now, if the library would have loaded statically I would have written a library function such as

```
void some_function(MyObject& o);
```

but since it is dynamically loaded I need some other signature. I was thinking the following: a common header like

```
//interface.hpp
extern "C" {
    void ob_w(void*);
}


struct MyObject {
   //...
}
```

Then, on the library side

```
//lib.cpp
#include "interface.hpp"

void ob_w(void* ptr)
{
    MyObject* p = (MyObject*)ptr;

    p->do_something();
}
```

and, for the main program

```
//main.cpp
#include "interface.hpp"

int main()
{
    void* handle = nullptr;
    void (*fptr)(void*);

    handle = dlopen(...)
    fptr = dlsym(...)

    MyObject foo;
    fptr((void*)&foo);

    //...
}
```

Looking around I found other similar questions, but in all of them the library was written in C and so different solution were adopted. Here both library and program are written in C++ and the void pointer is there just to avoid some adaptors. *I would like to know whether my approach is correct* (I tried on a linux machine and seems go give the correct result) and *safe*. In the case it is not, how could I pass the pointer of the object without introducing any overhead (for instance of some adaptor)?

Comment: Using C++ `vector` as parameter to a DLL is simply bad API design. You should strive to make it platform and language independent. If you wish to use C++ containers then keep them internal to the DLL. If you don't want overhead then don't use C++ standard libs.

Comment: You *can* use C++ types in signatures for dynamically linked libraries just fine. Theoretically you don’t have ABI stability but in practice that’s not an issue (especially when you control both the library and the consumer).

Comment: @Lundin `vector` was just an example. In my real code there is not `vector` but another template defined by myself. It was just an example to write less lines.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It defeats the whole purpose of using a DLL to begin with though. Why not link it statically if you are enforcing a particular language and ABI anyway?

Comment: @Lundin Those are not the only reasons for using DLLs. They aren’t even the main reasons, I’d argue. Other reasons include making a plugin architecture or other scenarios in which static linking is undesirable. Considerations for other languages were at best an afterthought when ld.so was developed. This *might* be different on Windows, no idea.

Comment: @Lundin For two reasons. 1. Depending on some configuration file the user may want to load different libraries (with same interface). 2. It was a requirement not depending on me.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The original reason in Windows was something ridiculous like saving space... libs didn't need to be installed if they were already available. Installers 'registered' DLLs for this purpose and every program kept dumping DLLs in various system libs. It was a mess. But assuming you got the calling convention/ABI right (there's 2 different but common ones in Windows), you could use them to share code between C++, Pascal, VB or whatever.

Comment: @Lundin To be honest I don’t think space saving is ridiculous at all, even today. I’m a huge opponent of static linking for anything except core components. All general-purpose libraries should be dynamically linked (and yes, I’m aware of the DLL hell but there are solutions for that, they’re just not used widely enough). I know I’m in a tiny minority with this view, though.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well I suppose it was fairly valid arguments back in the early days of Windows when program installations were delivered on 1.44MB floppy disks :) Nowadays though, the dynamic linking (and space saving) is mostly done by using some common run-time like .NET or Java VM. And I'm so glad that I don't do Windows programming nowadays :)

Comment: @Lundin Our multi-terabyte storage system routinely (!) runs out of storage space due to an abundance of Docker images lying around. And statically linked, redundantly present libraries (especially from Go …) are a large contributor to the size of these images. Space requirement of statically linked code is absolutely still a major concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoisting my comment into an answer: you definitely don’t need to change the signature of your function to make it work with dynamic linking, if you’re happy to require C++. That is, the following works:

```
extern "C" void some_function(MyObject& o) {
    o.do_something();
}
```

And then you could have a `main.cpp` as follows (fragment):

```
void* lib = dlopen("myobject.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if (not lib)  fail_spectacularly();

void (*some_function)(MyObject&) = reinterpret_cast<decltype(some_function)>(dlsym(lib, "some_function"));
if (not some_function) fail_spectacularly();

MyObject obj = whatever;
some_function(obj);
```